# How to build google's C++ libphonenumber library for Win32

Tags: c++, windows, boost, build, cmake

Some developers on our team are using the Java and C# versions of [libphonenumber](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/), a normalization library for international phone numbers.

They claim it is wonderful/magical/etc.

Unfortunately, being a Win32 C++ developer, my simple mind can't quite grasp all the wonder and magic of the CMake, boost, and host of other libraries and I can't build the library at all.

Can someone provide some hints ot tips or URLs to help point me in the right direction so that we can build this project and make use of it?

The current stumbling block is when trying to run CMake (following the instructions in the very short readme) I get the following error message:

```
> -- Could NOT find Boost
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I thought I set BOOST_ROOT correctly, but apparently either I set it wrong or I am missing other env vars.

How can I build this library?

We use VS 2008, but I also have VS 2010 on my machine.  I would be happy to get a build with either one.

Comment: Is this even available in C++, I thought it was Java, JavaScript only?

Comment: @Justin - http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/  - the problem is that the tools and documentation for C++ (especially for win32) are non-existent/horrible)

Comment: It requires: Boost(thread) - you must compile boost thread, Protocol Buffers, Google Test and libIcu. It is not a trivial task.

Comment: Um, I know I have to build those.  And I know it isn't trivial - thus the question here.  The question is HOW to build.  The CMake stuff is useless and does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your CMake may be outdated wrt to the Boost version you installed. Check the file FindBoost.cmake located in the CMake Modules directory. It must contain a section like this:

```
set(_Boost_KNOWN_VERSIONS ${Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS}
    "1.46.1" "1.47" "1.47.0"
    "1.46.0" "1.46" "1.45.0" "1.45" "1.44.0" "1.44" "1.43.0" "1.43" "1.42.0" "1.42"
    "1.41.0" "1.41" "1.40.0" "1.40" "1.39.0" "1.39" "1.38.0" "1.38" "1.37.0" "1.37"
    "1.36.1" "1.36.0" "1.36" "1.35.1" "1.35.0" "1.35" "1.34.1" "1.34.0"
    "1.34" "1.33.1" "1.33.0" "1.33")
```

Comment: Thanks. I added 1.47 and 1.47.0.  Unfortunately that does not seem to fix it.  How does cmake know where to go looking for boost?  I tried setting boost_root but clearly I am doing something wrong...

Comment: Did you pass `-DBOOST_ROOT=<your boost path here>` to the compiler?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass BOOST_INCLUDEDIR and BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the compiler; this way you can totally bypass the cmake module search.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS in FindBoost.cmake, step that you've already done
2. Change the CMakeLists.txt from \libphonenumber\cpp, change the line `find_package     (Boost 1.40.0 COMPONENTS thread)`

into

```
 set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON)
 set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      ON)
 set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME    OFF) //since CMake 2.8.3
 find_package (Boost 1.47.0 COMPONENTS thread)
```

3. Run `mkdir build` in \libphonenumber\cpp, cd `build`
4. Run cmake -G "your generator" -DBOOST_ROOT="you_path_to_boost_147_0 folder,", ex: `cmake -G "Visual Studio 10" ../ -DBOOST_ROOT="E:\libphonenumber\cpp\3rdparty"`

Comment: NOTE: Protocol Buffers can not be compiled with VS 2010

Comment: I have same issue. I am trying to compile protobuf library for windows using VS2010 but it fails. Is there any other ways? I have also one question is that can I compile libphonenumber library for windows without using boost???

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile it using [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), it is like a standard UNIX build environment but running on Windows. It usually is a lot easier to compile open source libraries using it than using Visual Studio.